# I want to calculate theoretical value of 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I want to calculate  theoretical value of  2D array.I have a 2D array like `arr = [[1,3,4],[5,7,9],[8,1,7]]`

So this 2D array's theoretical array is [5,3,7]
I tried to get the array by the code

```
theory = np.median(arr)
```

but when I print out theory, only 4.67 is returned.I read numpy document ,median method can be gotten array. What is wrong in my code?How should I fix this?

Comment: Are you not confusing mean and median ?

Comment: @Eolmar sorry,I made a mistake of 2D array's theoretical array.median  is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will calculate the median over the rows.

```
numpy.median(arr, axis=0)
```